# Photo gallery image margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a site for my new documentary and have found Bootstrap to be very helpful but I'm running into a bit of a problem:

I have 12 images, I'd like them to be arranged into 3 rows of 4, but make sure that with smaller screens this works out, so maybe on a mobile device it is only 1 image per column (or two).

Here is the site as is (no margins) http://athomewhileaway.org/gallery.html

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one

HTML

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

if you need one photo in small screen then you can remove  `col-xs-6` class from related div

CSS

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

This CSS property needs to remove space between the columns (Twitter Bootstrap set gutter width in default).

Thanks!

Comment: Hey this is great, thank you! However, when I shrink the window to simulate an iPhone, the photos stack on top of each other in a weird way: http://athomewhileaway.org/gallery.html

Comment: .col-xs-2 means they're going to shrink down to 1/6th of the screen, not 2.  I am not sure this is what you want.  If you want just two across, you need to use what I originally told you: .col-xs-6, or .col-xs-12 for a single column.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you! Is there any way to insure the photos will have even vertical distribution (margins) as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Note the xs (extra small) and sm (small)** You can use the .col-xs-6 (row of 2) or .col-xs-12 (single colum) for phones, and .col-sm-6/.col-sm-12 for tablet, up to 768px, I believe.  If you provide a fiddle I will hook you up with a better solution.  Learn more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

On extra small devices (most phones):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
             #Your Stuff
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
             #Your Stuff
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge---this appears to be working pretty well.  It is definitely collapsing to just rows of 2 on tablet-sized, but does go down to single column on phone.  You're doing a great job!  In case you're new to Bootstrap, you can just re-size your browser window to see how it's going to behave on different devices (make it skinnier).